# DBeaver: display datetime with milliseconds

Tags: mysql, datetime, format, dbeaver

This is MySQL 5.7 column:

```sql
`date` datetime(6) NOT NULL
```

I can see milliseconds using console:

```
mysql> select * from teq_log_1;
+----+----------------------------+-------+---------+---------+
| id | date                       | level | message | details |
+----+----------------------------+-------+---------+---------+
|  4 | 2019-08-01 12:23:34.123457 |     2 | test    | NULL    |
+----+----------------------------+-------+---------+---------+
```

but I cannot see milliseconds in DBeaver client:

[image]

There is format option for the `date` column (Right Click on `date` column / View/Format / Data Formats ...):

[image]

There are `Date`, `Time`, `Timestamp` & `Number` types (w/o `Datetime`). I set `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.sss` & `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.mmm` patterns but without result.

How can I display milliseconds/microseconds for `datetime(6)` in DBeaver (v. 6.1.3)?

Answer (score 12):

Turning on `Use native date/time format` did it for me.

Answer (score 4):

Using uppercase `SSS` as in `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS` shows milliseconds - you were using lowercase `sss`

Answer (score 2):

Using yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:S:Z in Timestamp under (for mac :: prefernces -> Editors -> Data Editor -> Data Formats ) helped me.

More on dBeaver documentation can be found here :: https://dbeaver.com/docs/wiki/Managing-Data-Formats/

Answer (score 1):

Probably, this is a cache related issue. I recreated my tables and reconnect DBeaver. Now I see milliseconds in DBeaver client:
[image]

... and I see microseconds in mysql console (but the last 3 digits are "0" - unixtime was inserted, w/o microseconds):

```
mysql> select * from teq_log;
+----+----------------------------+-------+-
| id | date                       | level | 
+----+----------------------------+-------+-
|  5 | 2019-08-01 11:10:27.247000 |     1 | 
|  6 | 2019-08-01 11:10:27.259000 |     1 | 
|  7 | 2019-08-01 11:10:27.636000 |     1 | 
|  8 | 2019-08-01 11:10:27.713000 |     1 | 
|  9 | 2019-08-01 11:10:27.758000 |     1 | 
| 10 | 2019-08-01 11:10:31.768000 |     1 | 
| 11 | 2019-08-01 11:10:32.300000 |     1 | 
+----+----------------------------+-------+-
```

Answer (score 0):

Using "Datetime" instead of "Date" as data type worked for me.

My java time's variable was--> Date now = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

I saved the "now" variable in DBeaver as "Datetime" type and this is the result--> 2022-11-11 15:15:17.000